# Solve ambiguous type reference

Tags: java

Even though I have a fully qualified reference here:

```
error: reference to Strict is ambiguous
          if (!(t instanceof akka.http.scaladsl.model.Multipart.FormData.Strict)) {
                                                                        ^
  both interface akka.http.scaladsl.model.Multipart.Strict in Multipart and interface akka.http.javadsl.model.Multipart.FormData.Strict in FormData match
```

The compiler is still complaining that the reference is ambiguous. How can I solve this?

Comment: Start by believing the compiler.  Is the syntax correct?  I see dollar signs in the docs: https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/Multipart.FormData$.Strict$.html

Comment: @duffymo javap tells me "public class akka.http.scaladsl.model.Multipart$FormData$Strict extends akka.http.scaladsl.model.Multipart$FormData implements akka.http.scaladsl.model.Multipart$Strict,akka.http.javadsl.model.Multipart$FormData$Strict,scala.Product,scala.Serializable". But in java source files you have to replace the `$` of enclosed classes with `.` afaik.  The classes ending in `$` are the result of compiling the companion objects.

Comment: I don't know Scala well.  Don't use classes like that.  Sorry, no insight from me.  "AFAIK" - the compiler isn't happy.  I'd dig into it more.  Your understanding isn't working.